# How to save multiple data at once in Python

Tags: python, saving-data

I am running a script which takes, say, an hour to generate the data I want. I want to be able to save all of the relevant variables to some external file so I can fiddle with them later without having to run the hour-long calculation over again. Is there an easy way I can save all of the variables I need into one convenient file?

In Matlab I would just contain all of the results of the calculation in a single structure so that later I could just load results.mat and I would have everything I need stored as results.output1, results.output2 or whatever. What is the Python equivalent of this?

In particular, the data that I would like to save includes arrays of complex numbers, which seems to present difficulties for using things like json.

Comment: See the Python docs on [Data Persistence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html) for a start. Note that we cannot really recommend a specific library without knowing the exact constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest taking look at built-in [shelve module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) which provides *persistent, dictionary-like object* and generally does work with all native Python types so you can do:

Write `complex` to some file (in my example it is named `mydata`) under key `n` (keep in mind that keys should be strings).

```
import shelve
my_number = 2+7j
with shelve.open('mydata') as db:
    db['n'] = my_number
```

Later retrieve that number from given file

```
import shelve
with shelve.open('mydata') as db:
    my_number = db['n']
print(my_number)  # (2+7j)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use pickle function in Python and then use the dump function to dump all your data into a file. You can reuse the data later.I suggest you find more about pickle.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend a json file. With json you can assign variables to keywords, just like dictionaries in stock python. The json package is automatically installed when installing python.

```
import json

dict = {var1: "abcde", var2: "fghij"}
with open(path, "w") as file:
    json.dump(dict, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii = False)
```

You can also load this from a file using the same api:

```
with open(path, r) as file:
    text = file.read()

dict = json.loads(text)
```

Edit: Json can also handle every datatype python can, so if you want to save an array you can just define that in the dict:

```
dict = {list1: ["ab", "cd", "ef"]}
```

Comment: "the data that I would like to save includes arrays of complex numbers" JSON cannot handle complex numbers natively.

Comment: TypeError: Object of type complex is not JSON serializable

Comment: Ah. okay. That's why you aren't on stackoverflow at 7am in the morning i guess.